# Cannot read property 'ScrollView' of undefined on React-Native and React-Navigation 3.x

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When I follow the instruction from https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html

and run the application, I have this error

Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js", which threw an exception: TypeError:

```html
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-art": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.8",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.11.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "uglify-es": "3.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.12",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.12",
    "@types/react": "16.8.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.60",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.8.1",
    "babel-jest": "24.7.1",
    "jest": "24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.50.0",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-art": "16.8.6",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.10",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0",
    "react-scripts-ts": "^3.1.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "ts-jest": "24.0.2",
    "tslint": "5.16.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.18.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install **react-native-gesture-handler** package to make it works   `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler` and link it.

Complete installation guide can be found here: https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/getting-started.html